# Optimizing mysql query for top 10 views

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table for tracking views to a particular page:

```
CREATE TABLE `views` (
  `time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `remote_host` varchar(255) default '',
  `r_clock` varchar(255) default '',
  `r_timezone` varchar(255) default '',
  `referer` varchar(255) default ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The query I've written for getting the top 10 is:

```
select count(*) as count, r_clock
from views where r_clock <> "html5" and r_clock not like "%-none"
group by r_clock
limit 10;
```

This query seems to be very slow however, as we get a lot of views, and with this query mysql ends up examining every row in the table.  Is there any simple way to optimize the query?  I don't think I'll be able to change the columns in the database, although adding indexing is probably fine.

Comment: What indexes have you created? If you don't yet have one on r_clock, this would be the first thing to try.

Comment: Looks like currently there are no indexes.  I'll try creating one on r_clock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to create an index on r_clock AND stop using the `%` at the beginning of the query. If you use `"%-none"`, you won't be able to use the index and it won't help.

If you can change the query (and obviously the data to work with it) to have the `%` at the end (e.g. `"none-%"`), this will allow it to use the index and will speed it up.

Comment: Thanks for this advice!  I did a describe on the query with the index, and it said it was examining fewer rows, even with the like in the query.  Unfortunately, I cannot change the data.  Would doing a substring `WHERE RIGHT(r_clock, 5) = '-none'` work with indexing?

Comment: This should not allow the use of the index any better as far as I know.